# CSS Bootstrap flex width - how to not expand parent by too long oneline text? Ellipsis

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, width

​I have driven into a complex issue with CSS and **flexbox**. The problem was to use those properties:

```
   ​text-overflow: ellipsis;
   ​white-space: nowrap;
   ​overflow: hidden;
```

but then if the text was too long, it extended our parent component width, **instead of adding "..."** and  ***yeah WE COULD SET MANUAL WIDTH*** of the parent to e.g. 20% or our child to e.g. 250px, but everybody knows it's bad solution (I KNOW THAT, so don't minus me, I didn't find any correct answer on the web).

Comment: Either add a proper answer or delete the question but don't mark it "Solved"

Answer (score 0):

So after many hours and asking for help to my senior dev, he added to the child class:

```
flex-basis: 0;
flex-grow: 1;
```

but the problem was still here and the final addition was just a simple:

```
   width: 0;
```

The parent is like:

```
   <div class="flex">
```

and now the child is:

```
    <div ng-if="value.LongText" class="flex-row">
        <span class="child-class" title="{{::value.LongText}}">{{::value.LongText}}</span>
    </div>
```